# Error when trying to return True/False values to a definition in python

Tags: python, break

```
def is_prime(x):
    if x < 2:
        return False
    elif x == 2:
        return True

    for i in range(2,x):
        if x % i == 0:
            return False
            break
        else:
            return True
```

The above code is mine from codecademy's python course, and i get a prompt telling me that when 9 is passed to the argument, the function returns True instead of False. I can fix this by doing:

```
    for i in range(2,x):
        if x % i == 0:
            return False
            break
    return True
```

I don't understand why the second bit of code works, and why the first bit doesn't. In fact, I would have thought the second bit of code wouldn't work: If the argument was 9, then when `i == 3, x % i == 0`. So the function gets a returned value of False, and the loop breaks. However, since the "return True" is NOT within the for loop, then after exiting the for loop, "return True" will execute anyway, so regardless of the input, the function will get returned a value of True, since that's the last line of code to be executed within the function?

Following that line of reasoning, I believed that my initial code would work, because if "return True" was within the for loop, then the break command would be executed (assuming the input was 9), AFTER the function has been returned a value of False. And since the "return True" line is within the the for loop, and since the break command will exit the for loop, then the last value given to the function would have been False, which would have been correct?

I apologise in advance if I have (very likely) misused certain terms, of have some flaw in my understanding of how the code works or is executed. I just can't seem to get my head around why the second bit of code works, but the first bit doesn't.

Cheers!

Comment: The indentation is wrong: dedent the last two lines one level, so the `else` matches the `for` not the `if`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `for` loop starts with `i == 2`. `9 % 2 == 1`, so it goes into the `else:` branch, and returns `True`.

Only if the entire loop is run and none of the numbers divided 9 should you return `True`.

Also, following `return ...` by `break` is useless - the function has already returned, so that break statement is never reached.

That's also the answer to your last question -- when `return` is executed, this function *ends*. Nothing else is done anymore, and the program continues (returns to) wherever it was when it called the function.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up! I had no idea the return function acted in the same way as break.

Comment: Yes, except that break exits the current loop, but return always immediately exits the current _function_. And it's not a function itself, it's a _statement_ (because otherwise it'd have to exit itself..)

Answer (score 1):

The first version didn't work because , when ever the if condition is false it returns True.Thus, when x==9 and i==2, 9%2!=0, thus it returns true.  Also, no need to use break statement as return statement returns the value from function and loop doesn't continue after return.

Following is the correct code

```
def is_prime(x):
    if x < 2:
        return False
    elif x == 2:
        return True

for i in range(2,x):
    if x % i == 0:
        return False
return True
```